# Landscape Mode is not working in Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, landscape-portrait

Landscape Mode is not working as I expected in Windows Phone Emulator. When I run my app I do not see a proper view of the keypad, such as I do when using Portrait Mode. How can I enable the keypad?

Comment: What do you mean by keypad? Your component or the one that appears whenever you enter text in TextBox?

Comment: than u for ur Reply.actually my problem is when i run my app at Landscape mode it will not be a proper view of touching Keypad like portrait mode while enter the text. i want to bring viewing of touching keypad as good at landscape mode when i enter the text, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can  you post a screenshot?

Comment: Pls give ur Email id i will send to ur mai

Answer (score 1):

It sound like orientation in Windows Phone Emulator?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402568%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: thank u for ur reply but my problem is touching keypad is not working proper in landscape mode in windows phone emulator, how can i correct this problem.